# Boolean operators precedence in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have some problems understanding some Pascal boolean expressions, and don't understand how chained `or / and` work.

- Why does `False or True and True` = `True`?
- Why does `False or True and True or False` = `True`?

As I can see it evaluates them from the right to the left, or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: It wouldn't  matter what the operator precedence was in these two expressions. They would always evaluate to these values. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch12.html for operator precedence in Free Pascal.

As you can see, `and` has a higher precedence over `or` operator:

```
False or True and True = False or (True and True) = False or True = True
False or True and True or False = False or (True and True) or False = False or True or False = True or False = True
```

Comment: The operator precedence in Pascal is defined by the *Pascal User Manual and Report,* Jensen and Wirth. Free Pascal isn't any different. As a matter of fact the precedence in these expressions doesn't affect the result.